# How to call multiple PromptDialog in botframework v3

Tags: botframework

I have a RootDialog in my application and from there I am calling another dialog - AskMultiplePromptsDialog using context.call() method.

In the StartAsync() method of AskMultiplePromptsDialog, I want to call a series of PromptDialog to take input from the user.

When I do this, the first prompt coming properly & after that, it is not going to the next promptDialog.

How can I call multiple PromptDialog sequentially one after another to collect input from the user?

Answer (score 0):

use form flow for this case

```
[Serializable]
public class SandwichOrder
{
    public SandwichOptions? Sandwich;
    public LengthOptions? Length;
    public BreadOptions? Bread;
    public CheeseOptions? Cheese;
    public List<ToppingOptions> Toppings;
    public List<SauceOptions> Sauce;

    public static IForm<SandwichOrder> BuildForm()
    {
        return new FormBuilder<SandwichOrder>()
                .Message("Welcome to the simple sandwich order bot!")
                .Build();
    }
```

You can start coding using the details provided in this link [Basic features of FormFlow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-formflow?view=azure-bot-service-3.0)

Comment: I don't want to use formflow rather want to use individual prompt dialogs